# increment a value by group and condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to increment a column per group and with a condition. Here is my data :

```
  df = tibble(SUBJ=c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6),rep(3,6)),PERIOD=rep(c(1,1,1,1,2,2),3),
                SAMPLE=rep(c("S1","S2","S3","S4","S1","S2"),3),
                TEST=c(F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F)


      # SUBJ PERIOD SAMPLE TEST 
  # <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <lgl>
  # 1      1      S1     FALSE
  # 1      1      S2     FALSE
  # 1      1      S3     FALSE
  # 1      1      S4     FALSE
  # 1      2      S1     FALSE
  # 1      2      S2     FALSE
  # 2      1      S1     FALSE
  # 2      1      S2     FALSE
  # 2      1      S3     TRUE 
  # 2      1      S4     FALSE
  # 2      2      S1     FALSE
  # 2      2      S2     FALSE
  # 3      1      S1     FALSE
  # 3      1      S2     FALSE
  # 3      1      S3     FALSE
  # 3      1      S4     FALSE
  # 3      2      S1     FALSE
  # 3      2      S2     FALSE
```

I want to create a variable SEQ , that would be incremented by group of SUBJ and PERIOD, where condition is "if test is TRUE" then value restart at 1.

I want to have this:

```
df = tibble(SUBJ=c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6),rep(3,6)),PERIOD=rep(c(1,1,1,1,2,2),3),
                    SAMPLE=rep(c("S1","S2","S3","S4","S1","S2"),3),
                    TEST=c(F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F),
                    SEQ=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2))



 # SUBJ PERIOD SAMPLE TEST     SEQ
  # <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <lgl>
  # 1      1      S1     FALSE  1
  # 1      1      S2     FALSE  2
  # 1      1      S3     FALSE  3
  # 1      1      S4     FALSE  4
  # 1      2      S1     FALSE  1
  # 1      2      S2     FALSE  2
  # 2      1      S1     FALSE  1
  # 2      1      S2     FALSE  2
  # 2      1      S3     TRUE   1
  # 2      1      S4     FALSE  2
  # 2      2      S1     FALSE  1
  # 2      2      S2     FALSE  2
  # 3      1      S1     FALSE  1
  # 3      1      S2     FALSE  2
  # 3      1      S3     FALSE  3
  # 3      1      S4     FALSE  4
  # 3      2      S1     FALSE  1
  # 3      2      S2     FALSE  2
```

I managed to have the count by group:

```
  df %>% group_by(SUBJ,PERIOD) %>% mutate(SEQ=rleidv(SAMPLE))
```

I try something like that to add a condition:

```
df %>% group_by(SUBJ,PERIOD) %>% mutate(SEQ=cumsum(TEST==F))
```

But I can't get the desire result .

Comment: You could do `df %>%
 group_by(SUBJ, PERIOD, GRP = cumsum(TEST)) %>%
 mutate(SEQ = 1:n()) `.

Comment: I think `1:n()` should be replaced with the dplyr-idiomatic `row_number()`. It isn't perfectly the same, and in general `1:n()` will work in this case without the usual risk of `1:length(x)`. (The problem with `1:length(x)` in general is that it only works correctly when `x` is not empty; when it is empty, that expression simplifies to `1:0` which fires *twice*, it is not empty.)